# Joda: how to get months and days between two dates

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I think I'm missing some subtlety here because everything I'm reading says this should work.  I need to get the months and days between two dates in Android.  That is to say, how many whole months plus any additional days.  I need this as numeric output, not a printed string.  Here's what I'm doing, using Joda:

```
void method(DateTime begin, DateTime end) {
    Period period = Period period = new Period(begin, end);
    final int months = period.getMonths();
    final int additionalDays = period.getDays();
```

The problem is `additionalDays` is always zero.  For example, July 1 2015 to November 29th 2015 should result in 4 months and 29 days, but I get 4 months and 0 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#getDays()) Period.getDays() will return 0 if it is unsupported. I am not sure why that would be unsupported, but I'd like to offer a different approach: use the `Days` and `Months` classes and their `monthsBetween()` and `daysBetween()` methods. Note that you'll have to subtract the months between, too:

```
// Get months
int months = Months.monthsBetween(begin, end).getMonths();
// Subtract this number of months from the end date so we can calculate days
DateTime newEnd = end.minusMonths(months);
// Get days
int days = Days.daysBetween(begin, newEnd).getDays();
```

If you don't preform this subtraction in the middle, you'll get incorrect results as you'll get *all* days.

Comment: Good idea, but wouldn't it be better to add the months to the begin than to subtract from the end?  Or would that have the same result?  I will try this, thank you.

Comment: I suppose they'd have the same results. The point is that you've already figured out the number of months, so you just want to know the difference in days. You may want to take the absolute value, too. Ex: If you did July 5 to Nov 1st, and you took away four months, you'd be comparing the dates between July 5 and July 1st which might return negative. I cannot test it, but be watchful of that, too.

Answer (score 2):

The [javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#Period%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) for the `Period` constructor you used

```
new Period(begin, end);
```

states

> Creates a period from the given interval endpoints using the standard
>   set of fields.

In other words, it is equivalent to

```
Period period = new Period(startTime, endTime, PeriodType.standard());
```

The [`PeriodType#standard()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/PeriodType.html#standard%28%29) method returns a `PeriodType` that supports the weeks field.

Your period, *July 1 2015 to November 29th 2015*, is actually 4 months and 28 days, where the 28 days get transformed into 4 weeks. So your `Period` object is actually of 4 months and 4 weeks.

If you had tried to create a `Period` from *July 1 2015 to November 30th 2015*, you'd have 4 months, 4 weeks, and 1 day.

Instead, create a `Period` with a `PeriodType#yearMonthDay()` that only supports years, months, and days fields.

```
period = new Period(begin, end, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
```

then you'd have a `Period` with 4 months, and 28 days, as it doesn't support weeks.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  I'm kind of glad I happened to be using a whole number of weeks because if it days had returned some seemingly random number it would have been even more confusing!  I already implemented it with Months and Days which works fine but if I were doing it over or have cause to revisit this I may change it to this technique.  It seems a little more straightforward.